# selecting a html link with a particular id and a html tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML code snippet like this:

```
 <div class="chartPeriodChangeOptions" id="id1">
    <a href="#" class="hourlyChartPeriod" data-period="day">D</a>
    <a href="#" class="hourlyChartPeriod" data-period="week">W</a>
 </div>
 <div class="chartPeriodChangeOptions" id="id2">
    <a href="#" class="hourlyChartPeriod" data-period="day">D</a>
    <a href="#" class="hourlyChartPeriod" data-period="week">W</a>
 </div>
```

I am trying to add a class="active", to link with id="id1" and data-period="day".

With the following code, I am able to choose the one with particular data value

```
$("a[data-period='" + someMethod() + "']").addClass("active");
```

How can I add id selection part to this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#id1 > a[data-period='" + someMethod() + "']").addClass("active")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be extensible use the 'starts with' selector:

```
$("div[id^='id'] > a[data-period='" + someMethod() + "']").addClass("active");
```

This will accept id="id1", id="id2", id="id3", ... etc

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#id1 a[data-period='" + someMethod() + "']").addClass("active");


});
```